# AVG function DB2 SQL run time error

Tags: sql, db2, runtime-error, runtime, average

I run this sql statemnt in DB2

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN AVG(TVAPC) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) 
FROM TABLE1
```

So far it was working.. TVAPC column is char(5).
But on run time we got that error. sql error +364 error. And we can't catch that error familiar case. Sometimes we get sometimes we cant for same case.

It seems run time error, but how can i prevent that error?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Most likely bad data in column TVAPC.  The value must be castable to a numeric type for AVG to make any sense in this context.   What is your Db2-server version and on which operating-system does Db2-server run ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment your post yet, so I'm going to post an "answer" with the risk of the stackoverflow royalty voting it down and trashing me for doing so. Check the data type of the column. When I run it, it works fine as long as the columns data type is a numeric type. If it happens to be your case (that the col. type isn't numeric) cast/convert it to Int.

```
--In case it isn't a numeric type...
SELECT (CASE WHEN AVG(CAST(column as int))>0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) 
FROM TEMP1234
```

Comment: `convert()` is not a DB2 function (at least not in DB2 LUW)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you taking the average of a *string*?  You should fix the data format.

In any case, you can check if the value has a number.  Here is one way (assuming the value is a number):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN AVG(CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRANSLATE(test_str, '*', ' 0123456789')) = 0 THEN TVAPC END) > 0
             THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END) 
FROM TABLE1
```